# How do I retrieve a list of posts based on a tag slug in WP Rest API V2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, wordpress, rest

I have an application that retrieves data from a Wordpress site using the WP Rest API V2. The API has recently been change from using a 'filter[tag]=' to a new syntax. I am looking to retrieve a list of posts within a specific tag.

Old syntax:

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[tag]=slug
```

The new syntax looks like this:

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?tags=id
```

It now takes an ID integer instead of a slug as argument. I have looked over the documentation but I can't seem to find a solution for this. I have no option of using the id, I can only use the slug!

The WP Rest API documentation can be found here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the list of tags by calling `http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/tags` before your requesting posts on a specifiy tagId. In that way you will find the tagId you need by filtering the data by your "slug". The demo API is not support CORS thats way I dont create a working fiddle.

#### Nested $http request bad example

```
 $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/tags'   
 }).then(function (result) {

      var filtered = filterFilter(result.data, { slug: 'dolor'});

      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?tags=' + filtered[0].id
     }).then(function (result) {
          console.log(result.data);
     });
 });
```

Comment: I have retrieved an object array with all the tags now. But I have troubles trying to match the tag 'slug' against the object array. I want to find the index of the right tag and return the id of this tag. Then I can use that to call the posts with a specific tag.

This code does not give me the location:

        var tags = succ;
        pos = tags.indexOf('baevresvamp');

Comment: @krillebimbim  I added a simple filter... this should help you.

Comment: It throws a filterFilter is not defined. I'm using AngularJS to do this. I've looked into the $filter but that only seems to be used in the view and not the controller.

Comment: @krillebimbim inject `filterFilter` into your controller. Its a AngularJS core based filter provider.

Comment: Thanks. The filter works but the entire method is still not working. Apparently the rest api only returns a minimum number of tags and not all. The filter therefore rarely finds the information needed.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the official [API docs for TAGS](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/tags/), you can search for strings in the tags schema with a request like this:

```
http://demo.wp-api.org/wp-json/wp/v2/tags?search=yourslug
```

The resulting JSON output will display tags containing the string you searched in any of the schema fields, like `slug`.

After you retrieved the desired tag, you can fetch the posts with that specific tag using it's ID (as suggested by @lin).